# Show current table value in combobox in addition to the query results

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a table, with a related value in another table. E.g. A Items table with a batch value from another table.

And

I have a form to enter how many of these items has been used and from which batch number they belong.

The batch number is from a dropdown, and batches can be finished(exhausted) and marked such in the table so they no more show in the dropdown.

All this works fine, until, I go back to a entry which was from a batch that has been finished. The combobox is empty although the (Already finished) batch number is mentioned in the table. This is perfectly normal as my query for the combobox is :

```
SELECT ItemBatch.ItemId, ItemBatch.ItemBatchNumber, ItemBatch.Finished, ItemBatch.ItemName 
FROM ItemBatch 
WHERE (((ItemBatch.Finished)=False) 
AND ((ItemBatch.ItemName)=[Forms]![ItemMasterForm]![ItemDataSheet].[Form]![ItemName]));
```

What I want is to show the current batch number as well. I tried to make this query get the current value, but wasn't successful. I tried to make a calculated field based on the dropdown and show its value, but it didnt helped out as well.

Is there any way I can show the batch number in the datasheet? 
I have to use a datasheet and not a form, because there will be many sub records for the main form, and having a form will be very uneasy.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what exactly you're trying to do and what's not working. You give us the combobox query but say you want to view some results in a datasheet view? What's not working with the datasheet view

Comment: The issue is :
"All this works fine, until, I go back to a entry which was from a batch that has been finished."
When a batch is finished, and u go to the product in the datasheet view, it doesnt appears there. I need to show the current value in the combobox.

The query I mentioned is the reason its not showing, I am trying to get a workaround, to append the current value in the query, or anyway else, if I can just show the current value also in the datasheet view.

Comment: Some more clarification: I have a form with a subform in datasheet view, in this view, the item is recorded with a batch number which can be selected from a dropdown( in the data sheet view). This dropdowns become empty, once the batch is marked is finished in its table.